# Intuition behind intensity parameter in Poisson point process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Consider a homogeneous Poisson point process as function of time, $N(t)$ with the parameter $\lambda$, where $N(t)$ represents the total number of occurrences (e.g. phone calls) up to and including time $t$.

Then, $E(N(t))=\lambda t$ with $N(t)$ is Poisson $(\lambda t).$

For a nonhomogeneous Poisson point process with the intensity function, $\lambda(t)$, we have:

$E(N(k))=\int_o^k \lambda(s) \, ds.$ with $N(t+h)-N(t)$ is Poisson $(\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s) \, ds)$ for a small $h>0$.

I want to understand why in the inhomogeneous case, we are looking at the difference between the total number of arrivals of now and a tiny bit in the future.

To homogeneous case makes sense to me, because if the arrival follows the Poisson distribution with the average number of arrivals per unit time, $\lambda$, then the expectation of that random variable standing at time $t$ should be simply the average times the time. I understand this as a special case of the Lebeague measure; $t$ can be spatial or finite-higher dimensional.

My questions are:

(1) In the non-homogeneous case, why is that we are looking at for a small $h>0$, the difference between $N(t+h)$ and $N(t)$ to characterize the this small difference follows a Poisson distribution?

(2) In the non-homogeneous case, is it problematic to make any characterization on $N(t)$?

Comment: For $h>0,$ $N(t+h)-N(t) \sim \operatorname{Poisson}\left( \int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)\, ds \right).$ Nothing in that statement requires $h$ to be small. It only requires $h$ to be positive.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok, thanks. Excellent.